# App ready for sale, but isnt shown in the app store?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval

So my app has passed the review, and is ready for sale. However, it has gone more than 30 hours now and i cant seem to find my app in the app store. Has anyone experienced this?

I´ve looked up earlier answers, but couldnt find any recent answers that solved this problem.

{
 "resultCount":0,
 "results": []
}

Comment: [App store approval is off-topic for Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/appstore-approval/info)

Comment: It might be worth checking another device if you haven't already. If not I would contact the developer support line. As most ive seen my app take 2 hours to show up 30 id contact apple. https://developer.apple.com/contact/#!/topic/select

Answer (score 2):

You can check via the bundle id:

```
http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.example
```

If the app still does not show up try contacting apple, or maybe your regions are not set up properly.

Comment: "resultCount":0,
 "results": []

i got a textfile containing this when i looked i up thorugh bundle id

Comment: it means your app is not on the app store, go ahead and contact apple

Comment: It showed up in the app store after 2 days. So i guess the time set by apple is unreliable